# Change value of text box ( dynamically created ) with ajax

Tags: jquery

I have to change the value of text box "autosaveoperation" in every 10 sec. with it I have to also insert data in my db.

I have tried to change the text box value on ajax `success` action but it does not changed.

```js
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  var form  = $("form");
  var firstInput = $(":input:not(input[type=button],input[type=submit],button):visible:first", form);
  jQuery(firstInput).after('<input name="autosave" type="hidden" value="new"/>')
  jQuery(firstInput).after('<input id="autosaveoperation" name="autosaveoperation" type="text" value="stop"/>')
  timePicker(10); 
});
</script>


<script>
var s;
function timePicker(vr) {
// function for count down timer...
    if (vr > 0)
    {
        vr--;
        s = setTimeout('timePicker(' + vr + ')', 1000);
    } else {
        clearInterval(s);


        
        jQuery("#autosaveoperation").val("start");


        var str = $( "form" ).serialize();
          $.ajax({
          url: 'myfile.php',
          type: "post",
          data: str,
          success: function(data){
          
            s = setTimeout('timePicker(' + 10 + ')', 5000);
            jQuery("#autosaveoperation").val("start");
            return false;
          },
          beforeSend : function(){
          },
        });    
    }
}
</script>
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>val demo</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="myfile.php" method="POST">
<input type="text" value="click a button">
</form>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: try jQuery("#autosaveoperation").live.val("start");

Comment: Check your ajax run success.